# How do i know whether user logs in with same computer or different computer using javascript OR php

Tags: javascript, php

I am developing a security api which will authenticate user on the basis of how he uses the system. which includes his typing patterns his typing speed and whole lot of stuff. in all these one variable is user's computer whether he logs in with his same computer every time or not. I think mac address of the computer will do the trick for me. I searched a lot and i couldn't find any result for this question.
Please help me. it will be good if your answer is in javascript or in php.

Comment: client mac address using php - not possible. Is this "security plugin" something a user will need to install in their computer?

Comment: actually this not for users my clients are B2B. business like ecommerce, e-learning and enterprises will implement my api on their own websites and users of these business will be authenticated when they try to login

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% fool proof to identify the machine or browser . But there are things you can try to check if user is using the same browser for subsequent connection. Cookies, user browser  details and os, remote address, etc

EDIT : Example for user browser details

```
function getUserBrowser() { 
    $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
    $bname = 'Unknown';
    $platform = 'Unknown';
    $version = "";

    //First get the platform?
    if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'linux';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'mac';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'windows';
    }

    // Next get the name of the useragent yes seperately and for good reason
    if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent)) { 
        $bname = 'Internet Explorer'; 
        $ub = "MSIE"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent)) { 
        $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox'; 
        $ub = "Firefox"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent)) { 
        $bname = 'Google Chrome'; 
        $ub = "Chrome"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent)) { 
        $bname = 'Apple Safari'; 
        $ub = "Safari"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent)) { 
        $bname = 'Opera'; 
        $ub = "Opera"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent)) { 
        $bname = 'Netscape'; 
        $ub = "Netscape"; 
    } 

    // finally get the correct version number
    $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
    $pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) . ')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
    if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
        // we have no matching number just continue
    }

    // see how many we have
    $i = count($matches['browser']);
    if ($i != 1) {
        //we will have two since we are not using 'other' argument yet
        //see if version is before or after the name
        if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)) {
            $version = $matches['version'][0];
        }
        else {
            $version = $matches['version'][1];
        }
    }
    else {
        $version = $matches['version'][0];
    }

    // check if we have a number
    if ($version == null || $version == "") {
        $version = "?";
    }

    return array(
        'userAgent' => $u_agent,
        'name'      => $bname,
        'version'   => $version,
        'platform'  => $platform,
        'pattern'    => $pattern
    );
}
```

and the you can use this function as

```
$browser = getUserBrowser();

$browser['userAgent'] //'userAgent'
$browser['name'] //'browserName'
$browser['version'] //'version'
$browser['platform'] //'platform'
$browser['pattern'] //'pattern'
```

for IP, you can check  different IP types like

```
'HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR'
```

and regarding cookie setup:

[Cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)

[How to Create, Read, Update and Delete a Cookie with PHP or Javascript](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/create-cookies-php-javascript)

Comment: I am already checking browser but this will not give the correct results because it is only the practice of user which was nothing to do with user computer.

Comment: I am also checking Operating system with some details but these can also be match with some other computer he used.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said there is no fool proof solution. User browser can install some plug-in,. In all these matter user security is very important

Comment: No i didn't try cookies.

Comment: I can't find the perfect code for cookies can you provide me the link of one good code. and it is an api not a plugin.

Comment: If you combine all these together, you can have a higher chance of identifying

Comment: But if you see my previous comment on post above. my target market is Businesses so i need fool proof check of system. any way can you please provide me the link of how to check the user computer through cookies because i am unable to find the good one.

Comment: i updated my answer, with samples, examples and links

Comment: Thank you for your Co operation.

Comment: Oxi this doen't work only NT is deifferent for different computer because they have different windows.

Answer (score 0):

When the user registers, at that time you take the user's IP address. Then, at the time of login, you check if the user logged in with the same computer or another computer.

Comment: Ip from same computer differs when user logs in from different place

Comment: u get the client machine name using javascript and then insert this machine name into database and at login time u check with machine  name

Comment: Does this solution works on every browser. i already searched this but the answers i got was No, or sometimes only working with IE.

Comment: get the client machine name using jquery u get name with no problem

Answer (score 0):

No one tells you their home-brewed solution. cookies and cookie-like objects, javascript, canvas. If you can detect ananomyzing methods its a huge flag to be used by admins. the harder the cookie is to clear the harder to deny they cleared it deliberately. Some sites are small and dont tolerate shenanigans.